# Why if you remove a regular fee from the list on an event does it not get removed from the price set in the database?

Tags: civievent, price-sets

If I set up an event and use the regular fees section rather than setting up a price set then it stores this information in a price set.
[image: Event regular fees page]
If I remove a value from this table then it stays in the database. If I know the price set id then I can find these fields via the UI
[image: Price options]
Why does the system keep this other value?
Having these other fields causes confusion when creating views because as far as a basic user can tell there is only one fee and there is no reason for them to expect there to be other ones hiding.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling of price field is actually helpful in case you need it in future and it is not shown anywhere else except price field browse page.

Eg:

- Configure an event with regular priceset(is_quick_config = 1) with three field options.
- Remove two of them (backend - civi disables it).
- Now, a user creates a new priceset from `Manage Price Set` page and configure on this event. At this point, your regular priceset is not lost. Its value of `is_quick_config` is changed to zero, hence it will be now shown on the list of PriceSet page.

So, it provides a flexibility of again choosing the original priceset for your event. You can also delete unwanted field options of it from `civicrm/admin/price/field/option?action=browse&reset=1&sid={set_id}&fid={field_id}` just like normal pricesets, if it is not used by any other event.

Comment: what about if a user has already registered using the now disabled amount, would that be another reason to keep the value in the db?

Comment: Yea, agree to that. as it isn't allowed to delete priceset/field if it is being used by any contribution row as per https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19721/unable-to-delete-price-field-from-price-set-used-for-contributions/19722#19722